# Retrieving values from excel sheet based on key using macros Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write some macros retrieve some data from another excel sheet based on a value in my current sheet.

Right now my current sheet(Sheet1) has this attribute "address" which I would like to map it to another sheet(Sheet2) which also has the same attribute "address". I would like to retrieve another cell value "road name" in sheet 2 based on the same address in both sheets.

My line of code looks like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 9).Value = ??
```

Anyone has any idea if there are any in-built functions in excel VBA that does this ?

Comment: Do you need VBA? From what I see, `vlookup()` might work? What does your data look like and what do ou expect to happen?

Comment: I want to auto populate Sheet 3, with the roadname, address. There are many rows so i wanna automate the process.

Comment: You may wanna post sample data- spreadsheet image or something - also what have you tried- vba?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, `VLookup` is probably the best solution.  If you don't want to enter a formula in your worksheet each time you enter a new "address", you can use `VLookup` in VBA in one of two ways.

Firstly, you could write a formula to Excel so that Excel performs the `VLOOKUP`:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet2!C1:C2,2,FALSE)"
```

Secondly, you can use the `Application.VLookup` function so that VBA does the `VLookup` and writes a value to the cell:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 9).Value = Application.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 8).Value, _
                                                           Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B"),2,False)
```

---

Note: In both cases I have assumed that the "address" is in column H of "Sheet1", and that "address" and "road name" are in columns A:B of "Sheet2".